# Plugin event only when Email activation

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, user

I am just referring the Joomla User plugin events in the URL https://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events/User/en

```
onUserLogin
onUserAuthenticate
onUserBeforeSave
```

Just wondering which one will help me to do something only when they validating their email address from the Email activation link?

Note: During the time of Email activation I have to connect to a SOAP server and validate few stuffs and then only allow him to activate the account.

Answer (score 3):

you can do it this way:
You create a user plugin (NOT authentication plugin, this one is separate), i called mine testwise "checkmail".
In that plugin put the onUserBeforeSave callback, in wich you can check if the account is getting activated like this:

```
class PlgUserCheckmail extends JPlugin
{
    /**
    * Application object
    *
    * @var    JApplicationCms
    * @since  3.2
    */
    protected $app;

    /**
    * Database object
    *
    * @var    JDatabaseDriver
    * @since  3.2
    */
    protected $db;


    public function onUserBeforeSave($oldUser, $isNew, $newUser)
    {
        if(!$isNew)
        {
            if(isset($oldUser['activation']) &&
               !empty($oldUser['activation']) &&
               isset($newUser['activation']) &&
               empty($newUser['activation']))
            {
                // These commands in here are only triggered if the user is activating his account
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps =)

[edit]: Ah, i almost forgot: This plugin goes inside the plugins/user directory!

Comment: Thanks. I will try. Should I return false for not to activate the member in case of unapproval?

Comment: Deleted my previous comment that this doesn't work -- I had a stupid bug. It does work, and it works great. Thanks for the tip.  :)